# ImageAdd with specific position

Tags: image-processing, image

Consider the following code :

```
imgZero= Image[Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {i, 500}, {j, 500}]]
imgOne= Blur[RegionImage[Region[RandomPolygon[7]]], 30]
ImageAdd[imgZero, ImageResize[0.6*imgOne, 35]]
```

Running it will give somtehing like this :[image]

I would like to do the same but I want to be able to put imgOne at any position I want.
`ImageCompose` offers this option but it does not blend the two images, it superimposes one on the other, and you get an unwanted black background.

[image]

Any solution ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may first create an image with the blur and black background of the final size. Then you can extract the data. Then you may rotate the data in x and y direction, to get the blur where you want. Finally you add the blur to the original picture.

Here is an example:

```
imgZero = Image[Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}], {i, 500}, {j, 500}]];
imgOne = Blur[RegionImage[Region[RandomPolygon[7]]], 30];
img0 = Image[Table[0, {i, 500}, {j, 500}]];
img1 = ImageAdd[img0, ImageResize[0.6*imgOne, 35]];

shift[x_, y_, img_] := Module[{dat},
  dat = ImageData[img];
  dat = Transpose[RotateLeft[#, Round@y] & /@ Transpose@dat];
  dat = RotateLeft[#, Round@x] & /@ dat;
  Image[dat]
  ]
Manipulate[
 ImageAdd[imgZero, shift[x, y, img1]]
 , {{x, 0}, -250, 250}, {{y, 0}, -250, 250}
 ]
```

[image]